# prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{n^2x}{1 + n^2x^2\log n}$ converge but not uniform

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> I have to prove that the sequence of functions
>   $$
> f_n(x) = \frac{n^2x}{1 + n^2x^2\log n},
> $$ converges.

So I think that I can just show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (f_n) = 0$ pointwise. But to show that the sequence does not converge uniformly, I need to show that $f_n$ has a point of maximum $x = \frac{1}{n \sqrt{\log n}}$ and at this point, the limit is equal to infinity. Is that correct?

And finally I need to show that $\forall \alpha > 0$ in the interval $\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\alpha,+\alpha)$, the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly, but I don't have ideas how to do it.

Comment: You do not need to prove that the limit is infinity, you just need to prove that the sequence does not go to zero.

Comment: Okay, I got it, for example $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x^n)$. When $x = \sqrt[n]{1/2}$ we have $f_n = 1/4$, thus is not uniformly convergent, correct?

Comment: Yes, because the max-norm is always at least $1/4$ so cannot go to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1).\ $ If $x=0$ the sequence clearly converges to $0$. If not, then $|f_n(x)|\le \frac{1}{x\log n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ so $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent.

$2).\ $ The trouble will be near zero, so take $x_n=1/n$. Then $x_n\to 0$ whereas $f_n(x_n)\to \infty$, and so $(f_n)$ is not uniformly convergent.

$3).\ $ $f_n$ is odd for each $n\ge 1$ so it suffices to check $[\alpha,\infty).$ In this case,$\ |f_n(x)|\le \frac{1}{\alpha\log n}$ so $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded, and so converges uniformly.

Comment: Because $f_n(1/n)=n/(1+\ln n)$

Comment: I had misread the numerator as $n^2x^2$.